# Symfony link_to popup on the layout doesnt work

Tags: php, popup, symfony-1.4, link-to

I have a layout base page. On this page I have a link_to to open up a popup:

```
<?php $options = 'left=100,top=10,width=650,height=375,location=no,scrollbars =yes,resizable=yes,directories=no,status=no,toolbar=no,menub ar=no' ?>
<?php echo link_to(image_tag($profile_picture, 'size=25x25') .' ' .$sf_user->getAttribute('user')->getUsername(), '/frontend_dev.php/user/' .$sf_user->getAttribute('user')->getId(),
    array(
    'popup' => array('popupWindow', $options)
    )
); ?>
```

When I click the link the user page opens but not in a popup window. But when I click the same link in the user page, it opens the user page in a popup window. I even tried a plain HTML a link with an onclick:

```
<a href="http://google.com" onclick="window.open(this.href, 'popupWindow', 'width=500, height=500')">Google</a>
```

And it still didn't open a popup window from the layout, but from the user page it does!

Can someone please explain to me what I'm doing wrong?

Maybe you're asking how I'm loading the userpage, well like this:

```
<?php echo $sf_content ?>
```

And user page does simple HTML with PHP, so nothing special about that.

EDIT:

Well it had something to do with the index page of the sfGuestBookPlugin, it has a

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
});
</script>
```

part, and I had my own part of JS in another script tag at the bottom of the file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var open = true;
    $(".form-title").click(function() {
        if(open) {
            $(".openClose").text("▼");
            open = false;
        } else {
            $(".openClose").text("▲");
            open = true;
        }
    });
</script>
```

What helped is move this part within the $(document).ready() part. But I'm still curious about why this is helping. If you could please explain?

Comment: maybe you have a JS error somewhere? Also by layoutdo you mean your `apps/APPNAME/templates/layout.php` or something else?

Comment: When I check firebug for errors, it doesn't show me any, so that should be fine. It even is a symfony helper function.
And that's exactly what I mean with the layout.

Comment: yeah but js errors elsewhere on the page could potentially be preventing it from running. That said something is different between the code or the output on the two pages because one works and the other doesnt.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately you were right, I'm using the sfGuestBookPlugin which uses a lot of JS. That's probably what is interfering with the popup. Now I'll have something to look for.